# TLS, расшифровка сообщения 'Finished'

Tags: c#, ssl, hex, tls

Здравствуйте. Прошу мне помочь, что дальше делать с этим сообщением (HEX)

Сообщение в НЕ расшифрованном виде:

```
16030100309a547b7c3d1f71601a3686deb6496e60ca02f93cbcd3ed921f47ff5836a606e7d632f0c5e8a1585a964dc3095eeabeea
```

Сообщение в расшифрованном виде:

```
1400000cdb4dc24d336cb06128a40a9ec0450f0446643ee9480663586be1735f10fb28d60b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b
```

Я использую CipherSuite: `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` `0x2f`. Версия TLS - `1.0`

Я получил master secret и key exchange верно, поскольку я расшифровал это сообщение. Ниже отрывок кода:

```
byte[] CKE_Length = Reader.ReadBytes(3);         //ClientKey Exchange
byte[] CKE_pubkKeyLength = Reader.ReadBytes(2);  //ClientKey Exchange
byte[] CKE_pubkKey = Reader.ReadBytes(256);      //ClientKey Exchange


byte[] pre_master_secret = Program.PrivateKey.Decrypt(CKE_pubkKey, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
byte[] master_secret = TlsUtilities.PRF_legacy(pre_master_secret, "master secret", ByteArray.Concat(ClientRandomBytes, ServerRandomBytes), 48);
byte[] key_block = TlsUtilities.PRF_legacy(master_secret, "key expansion", ByteArray.Concat(ServerRandomBytes, ClientRandomBytes), 104);

byte[] client_write_mac = new byte[20]; 
byte[] server_write_mac = new byte[20];

byte[] client_write_key = new byte[16];
byte[] server_write_key = new byte[16];

byte[] client_write_iv = new byte[16];
byte[] server_write_iv = new byte[16];


Buffer.BlockCopy(key_block, 0, client_write_mac, 0, 20);
Buffer.BlockCopy(key_block, 20, server_write_mac, 0, 20);
//40
Buffer.BlockCopy(key_block, 40, client_write_key, 0, 16);
Buffer.BlockCopy(key_block, 56, server_write_key, 0, 16);
//104
Buffer.BlockCopy(key_block, 72, client_write_iv, 0, 16);
Buffer.BlockCopy(key_block, 88, server_write_iv, 0, 16);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заголовок зашифрованного сообщения:

```
16 - тип сообщения - handshake
0301 - версия SSL
0030 - длина сообщения
```

Расшифрованное сообщение:

```
14 - тип handshake сообщения - finished
00000c - длина сообщения
db4dc24d336cb06128a40a9e - сообщение
c0450f0446643ee9480663586be1735f10fb28d6 - HMAC
0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b - паддинг
```

Если вы пишите свой сервер, вы должны проверить паддинг, код аутентификации (HMAC), и само сообщение. Вы используете TLS 1.0, значит должны проверить, соответствуют ли оно спецификации.

Согласно [TLS 1.0 спецификации, раздел Finished](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246#section-7.4.9) эти 12 байт должны быть равны:

```
PRF(master_secret, finished_label, MD5(handshake_messages) + SHA-1(handshake_messages)) [0..11]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Хотел ещё спросить: 1. Что содержится в сообщении (в расшифрованном)? Желательно скажите, как расшифровать (ключи все есть) 2. Используется SHA, точно MD5. 3. Ещё волнует вопрос, как составить handshake messages и включает ли оно ChangeCipherSpec? 4. Для чего нужен падинг?

Comment: 1. 12 байт сообщения Finished нужны для того, что бы удостоверится, что handshake прошел успешно, и на клиенте/сервере сгенерированы одинаковые ключи. Вы сами приложили расшифрованное сообщение, разве не вы его расшифровали? 2. Не понял? 3. Прочитайте RFC, там написано, что включаются все сообщения, и ChangeCipherSpec 4. Паддинг нужен для блочного шифра (AES), он может шифровать только сообщения длиной кратной 16 байт

Comment: Про ChangeCipherSpec я ошибся выше. В спецификации написано, включаются все handshake сообщения, но ChangeCipherSpec не является handshake сообщением согласно спецификации.

Comment: 1. В расшифрованном сообщении есть ещё одно сообщение, что там? db..9e

Comment: А как получить handskake messages?(

Comment: 2. Я использую ciphersuite, который работает с SHA, а предлагается хэширование MD5.

Comment: 1. db..9e - это то, что вы должны вычислить на своей стороне, и сверить с тем, что прислала другая сторона 2. так устроен TLS 1.0, для вычисления Finished нужен MD5 3. что бы получить handshake данные, нужно сохранять все сообщения пересланные по сети, без заголовков record layer

Comment: 1.То есть у меня должно получиться тоже самое?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72195/discussion-between---and-zergatul).